# An error occurred when I used "CM.make();" in SML,Ubuntu

Tags: sml, smlnj, cm

This is my first time that I used ubuntu and SML/NJ.  And this question occurred to me when i used the expression `CM.make()`:

```
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.76 [built: Tue Oct 22 14:04:11 2013]
- CM.make() ;

[autoloading]

[library $smlnj/cm/cm.cm is stable]

[library $smlnj/internal/cm-sig-lib.cm is stable]

[library $/pgraph.cm is stable]

[library $smlnj/internal/srcpath-lib.cm is stable]

[library $SMLNJ-BASIS/basis.cm is stable]

[autoloading done]

stdIn:1.2-1.11 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]

  operator domain: string

  operand:         unit

   in expression:

    CM.make ()
```

I don't know why and where I'm wrong.
Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 4):

```
stdIn:1.2-1.11 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: string
  operand:         unit
  in expression:
    CM.make ()
```

What the above error says is that `CM.make` is a function that accepts a string argument ("operator domain: string"), but you gave it a unit `()` argument ("operand: unit").

`CM.make` expects a path to a .cm file where you list your source files:

```
group is
  file-1.sml
  file-2.sml
```

Save the above in a file called `sources.cm` and then load it using `CM.make "sources.cm"`. Don't forget to list your actual source files, not `file-1.sml` and `file-2.sml`.

There are other things that you can do with .cm files, which are covered in the [CM manual](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/CM/), but the above should be enough to get you started.